# Determine the limit if it exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given

$S = 1 + r + \frac{1}{2}r^2 + \frac{1}{3}r^3 + \cdots$

Check its convergence and determine the limit of $S$ if it exists.

My attempt:
I have checked the convergence of $S$ by using ratio test.  I found that $S$ will convergent if $r < 1$.  Now,  if $S$ is convergent, then $S$ must be has a limit, is not it? The next question is asking for the limit and I am stuck at this.  Please help,  regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x| < 1$. Then notice
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n} \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
So
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n} = 1+\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-x} = 1- \log(1-x).$$

Comment: It deduces that $S$ willl convergent to $- \log(1-x)  + 1$?

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the $1$ at the beginning of your original series.

Comment: is not you change $S$ into summation form,  but you leave 1 as $S = 1 + \cdots$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  Mark.  I understand right now.  :)

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting my answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left) to let others know that you're question has been satisfactorily answered.

Comment: Why don't we have to worry about a $+c$?

Comment: I equally well could've included the integration constant by writing $1 + \sum \frac{x^{n}}{n} = 1 - \log(1-x) + C$. Then, setting $x = 0$ on both sides of the equation yields $1 = 1 + C$, so $C = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$S-1=-(-r)+\dfrac{1}{2}(-r)^{2}-\dfrac{1}{3}(-r)^{3}+\cdots=-\log(1-r)$.

Comment: which will obviously have issues if $r \ge 1$

Comment: Yes, true, but OP has noticed that.

Comment: though OP has not yet stated issues when $r \le -1$